# Dúvidas sobre banco de dados e Android

Tags: android, sql, banco-de-dados

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto para a faculdade que se trata de um jogo multiplayer para Android de perguntas e respostas (estilo Perguntados). No desenvolvimento do jogo, preciso criar um banco de dados para armazenar as perguntas, suas respostas, e a opção correta. O jogo acessa esse banco de dados e escolhe uma pergunta aleatória. Como nunca mexi com banco de dados antes, tenho dúvidas sobre como implementar esse banco de dados.

Comment: Sua dúvida é exatamente em que parte da implementação?

Comment: Como inserir as perguntas no banco de dados

Comment: Pensando rápido, eu criaria uma tabela para as perguntas (coluna questao e coluna codPergunta), uma tabela para respostas erradas (coluna codQuestao, coluna resposta1, coluna resposta2 e coluna cedRespErrada) e uma tabela para resposta certa (coluna cadQuestao, coluna respostaCerta e coluna codResoCerta)

Comment: Era isso que queria saber?

Comment: Precisa de um editor de banco de dados, não é? Qual você me recomenda?

Comment: O valentina studio é bom?

Comment: Desculpe, eu nunca usei um editor, eu uso comandos SQL mesmo. Se você colocar o banco em um servidor web, a maioria deles utiliza o myPHP admin, você conseguirá utilizar tranquilamente.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Se você for manter os dados em um banco de dados local você irá usar SQLite, caso queira algo remoto, pesquise sobre WebServices.

Answer (score 1):

Se o jogo é para Android, você vai precisar usar o banco de dados [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/about.html) e o [SQLiteMan](http://sqliteman.yarpen.cz/) para gerenciar os dados do seu banco de forma mais fácil.

Um exemplo simples de como estruturar suas informações seria criar uma tabela com os seguintes campos: **_id, pergunta,  opcao_a, opcao_b, opcao_c, opcao_d, resposta**

**Observações:**

1. Como você disse que o jogo é parecido com o **Perguntados**, eu assumi que as perguntas são de multipla escolha e há 4 opções de resposta (a,b,c,d) para cada pergunta com apenas uma resposta correta.
2. O campo **_id** é utilizado para fazer as consultas e mostrá-las utilizando um [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html), então caso você não vá utilizar CursorAdapter, não precisa usar o _id.

Sendo assim, um passo-a-passo rápido seria:

1. Instale o SQLite e o SQLiteMan
2. Crie uma pasta chamada **assets** em "caminho do seu porjeto/app/src/main"
3. Abra o SQLiteMan , crie um arquivo **meubanco.db**
4. Execute o seguinte código SQL ( essa tabela é apenas uma sugestão, você pode criar o esquema que achar melhor)

   ```
   CREATE TABLE perguntas (
       _id INTEGER PRIMARY_KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
       pergunta TEXT,
       opcao_a TEXT,
       opcao_b TEXT,
       opcao_c TEXT,
       opcao_d TEXT,
       resposta TEXT
   );
   ```
5. Salve o arquivo na pasta **assets**

Executando esses passos, você já terá o banco de dados pronto para uso em sua aplicação. Depois viria a parte mais chata: Acesso das informações do banco pela aplicação.

**Como você disse que nunca mexeu com bancos de dados, sugiro que você dê uma olhada nos conceitos básicos de [Banco de Dados](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banco_de_dados) e [SQL](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) ( principalmente na parte de [palavras-chave](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Palavras-chave_em_SQL))**

Agora é só meter a mão na massa e quando você tiver dúvidas mais específicas , sinta-se a vontade para tirar suas dúvidas aqui :-)

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que nesse caso, há somente duas entidades envolvidas: perguntas e respostas.
A resposta estar correta ou não é apenas um atributo da resposta.
Vou colocar um código SQL "genérico", que você vai precisar adaptar para o SQLite.

```
CREATE TABLE perguntas (
  id NUMBER,
  pergunta VARCHAR(150)
);
CREATE TABLE respostas (
  id NUMBER,
  resposta VARCHAR(150),
  correta BOOLEAN,
  id_pergunta NUMBER
);
```

Espero que ajude.